# Reduce Space between image & text on button Xamarin Forms

Tags: button, xamarin.forms

There is unwanted space between `image` & `text` on `Button`. I want to reduce it. This is my code

```
<Button  
    Padding="4,0,0,0" 
    FontFamily="{StaticResource mediumFontFamily}"
    ImageSource="ic_qr_refresh.png"                                                                 
    WidthRequest="110"                                    
    HeightRequest="35"
    FontSize="Small"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    Text="Refres">
</Button>
```

This is how it is showing
[image]

I want to reduce space between `refresh icon` and `Refresh text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use the Padding of 50 or more

```
<Button  
Padding="4,0,50,0" 
FontFamily="{StaticResource mediumFontFamily}"
ImageSource="ic_qr_refresh.png"                                                                 
WidthRequest="110"                                    
HeightRequest="35"
FontSize="Small"
VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
Text="Refres">
```

[image]

Comment: ... and if you want to push icon to the right, also use left Margin: `<Button Margin="20,0,0,0" Padding="..."`. In this case, you might use a smaller padding value.